# Can I return 404 or 403 if file does not exist?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, rewrite

Can I return a 404 or 403 status if anyone tries to open /?a=b AND 2=2 in php files?
I mean: I want to return 403 or 404 status if anyone try to open `index.php/?a=b AND 2=2`

My vhost is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    root /var/www/mysite.com/public_html;
    index index.php;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    root /var/www/mysite.com/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 240;                    
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
    access_log        off; 
    log_not_found     off; 
    deny              all; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file does not exist, a 404 should be returned automatically.

Since the file aparently exists you could return a 404 from the php file with `http_response_code(404);` under the desired condition(s).

But if your goal is to prevent SQL-Injection, you should escape ALL input when building your query and not rely on external mechanism to filter that...